# How to detect collision of sprites which are in a CCArray in cocos2d-x (c++) ios game

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, cocos2d-x

I am a beginner in cocos2dx ios game development.I have 12 sprites in a CCArray and they are falling from top to bottom of the screen randomly. Any sprite can appear any time.
I have done layering that the sprite at array index 0 will come at layer 12 and at index 1 will come at layer 11 and so on.So that the sprite coming first appear ahead of the sprite coming second.
But the point is this situation is not always true.The sprites can come like index 5 first and then index 4 and so on.
So how to detect collision of the sprites present in the same array such that if they touch each others bounding box then I can make them slow for a second or something else so that they don't overlap with each other.I am not using Box2d and don't want to use it. I just want answer without using box2d and only in cocos2dx using c++.Anyone who can help me
Thanks

Comment: This largely depends on the shape of your sprites (circular, rectangular, or otherwise) as well as how you want to handle the collisions. Could you provide some more information?

Comment: they are rectangular and of same shape

Comment: suppose some rectangular boxes are falling from top to bottom and coming randomly.these boxes are on array.and rest the information is in question

Comment: For rectangular collisions collision detection is generally pretty simple. See an implementation of this I wrote [here](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/SimpleGameEngine/blob/master/Rectangle.cpp#L27). If the boxes have rotation, this will of course be more difficult.

Comment: my  main question is how to detect in an array...

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i + 1 < numBoxes; i++) { for(int j = i + 1; j < numBoxes; j++) { if(collision(boxes[i], boxes[j])) { /* Handle collision */ }}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCArray mbox;

Write this code in update

```
for(int i = 0; i<mbox_count();i++)
  for(int j = i+1; j<mbox_count();j++)
   {
     CCSprite* sp = static_cast<CCSprite*>mbox->objectatindex(j);
     CCSprite* sp1 = static_cast<CCSprite*>mbox->objectatindex(i);
     if(sp1->boundingBox().intersectsRect(sp->boundingBox()))
    {
    //whatever you want to do;
    }
   }
```

Comment: but here is a problem..if i put this code in a function and call it after each second..it is called in the beginning i*j times because at the time of creation of sprites and adding the sprites to an array they all are at same position

Answer (score 0):

@Rajan I would recommend using CC_FOREACH when you search through a CCArray because I've had memory leak issues using Singhaks answer above. Instead you can write your code like this:

```
// we need two objects to look at each element in our array
CCObject*   obj_x = NULL;
CCObject*   obj_y = NULL;

CCARRAY_FOREACH(_arr_x, obj_x) {
    CCArray* _obj_x_arr = (static_cast<CCArray*>(obj_x));

    CCARRAY_FOREACH(_obj_x_arr, obj_y) {
        Sprite* _spriteImage_y  = (static_cast<Sprite*>(obj_y));
        Rect rect_a         = IntersectionPoint_A -> getBoundingBox();
        Rect rect_b               = _spriteImage_y  -> getBoundingBox();

        if (rect_b.intersectsRect(rect_a)) {                
            // do whatever you like in here   
        }
    }

}
```

I wrote more in detail here in case you need it:
https://kagato0110.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/how-to-traverse-through-a-2d-ccarray-cocos2dx-c-on-android/